# How to access specific record from fixture/*.json file into sepcific test case in cypress?

Tags: javascript, json, mocha.js, cypress, fixtures

testdata.json

```
[
    {
        "case_id": 1,
        "case": "Login with valid data as wholesaler",
        "username": "admin",
        "password": "password",
        "result": "pass"
    },
    {
        "case_id": 2,
        "case": "Login with valid data as reseller",
        "username": "myreseller.admin",
        "password": "password",
        "result": "pass"
    },
    {
        "case_id": 3,
        "case": "Login with valid data as subscriber",
        "username": "mytenant.admin",
        "password": "password",
        "result": "pass"
    }
]
```

login.spec.js

```
  before(() => {
    cy.fixture('testdata').then((datajson) => {
      testdata = datajson
      return testdata
    })
  })
------it blocks-----
  it.only('TC03 - Login with valid data as subscriber', () => {
    cy.login(testdata.username, testdata.password);                            
    cy.title().should('equal', 'Home');
    cy.logout();
-------more it blocks-------
```

How to use it properly so that line 2 returns
{testdata.username = mytenant.admin || testdata.password = password}
fetching specifically from 3rd record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Cypress Docs there are two ways described how you can handle those JSON files from the fixtures folder: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Examples

**1. Option**

Load your testdata.json using cy.fixture():

```
cy.fixture('testdata.json').as('testdata');
```

**2. Option (my recommendation)**

In your login.spec.js you can import all relevant json files from your fixtures folder:

```
import testdata from '../fixtures/testdata.json';
```

You can then directly use them as follows to for example use the username and password for the first user:

```
  it.only('TC03 - Login with valid data as subscriber', () => {
    cy.login(testdata[0].username, testdata[0].password);                            
    cy.title().should('equal', 'Home');
    cy.logout();
  })
```

Comment: I am aware of using index, but if data is shuffled in testdata.json then test case will break. Is there any alternative without using indexing.

Comment: Sure, my example was now directly related to your code, but if you import the test data like shown above, you can treat it like normal javascript data structures. This means you could for example just search your user list for an user object with a certain property value using testdata.find() and thus be independent from possible shuffling --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#find_an_object_in_an_array_by_one_of_its_properties

Comment: Thanks Sebastiano. I found the solution to that problem. I've used unique id "case_id" in each data to fetch that specific record. PS: testdata.find() helped to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

Your json is structured as an array, so you need to get elements from it using index or restructure your `testdata.json` fixture.

Try this:

```
it.only('TC03 - Login with valid data as subscriber', () => {
    cy.fixture('testdata').then((dataFixture) => {
        cy.login(dataFixture[2].username, dataFixture[2].password);
        cy.title().should('equal', 'Home');
        cy.logout();
    })
})
```

P.S. Assuming your `testdata` is imported at the top of the file.

Comment: I am aware of using index, but if data is shuffled in testdata.json then test case will break. Is there any alternative without using indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
describe('Some Test Suite', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.fixture('testdata').then(function (testdata) {
      this.testdata = testdata
    })
  })

  it.only('TC03 - Login with valid data as subscriber', function () {
    cy.log(this.testdata[2].username) //prints mytenant.admin
    cy.log(this.testdata[2].password) //prints password
    cy.login(this.testdata[2].username, this.testdata[2].password)
    cy.title().should('equal', 'Home')
    cy.logout()
  })
})
```

Make sure that you are getting the fixtures file in `beforeEach()` so that the fixture is available for all test cases.

Comment: I am aware of using index, but if data is shuffled in testdata.json then test case will break. Is there any alternative without using indexing.