# How to import file from general path in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a file called 'contents' in cypress.
in my test file I want to import this file.

I do the following :

```js
import contents from 'C:/Users/asus/cypress/support/contents';
```

But I want to make it more general path (not contain my own path).
I tried to import it inside the index file in cypress.

As follow:

```js
import './contents'
```

But it is not working by this way. Cypress will throw an error that contents is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to export that file

```
const contents = {
    // Your data
}
export { contents };
```

You can import files like this way

```
import { contents } from '../support/contents.js'
```

If `../support/contents.js` is not working Please use `../../` to get the root directory of your system like `../../support/contents.js`.
Please replace your file extension with `.js`.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the data type and assuming that the exact location of the file doesn't matter, I would recommend moving the file to the */fixtures* folder and importing it as recommended in the Cypress docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture). So you can use a relative path for the import in your test like:

```
import contents from '../fixtures/contents';
```

You can also find an example for importing a JSON file in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70445213/6135684).